# Using multiple groups for "People or Groups" column

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, limitations, person-or-group

I have a SharePoint group of people that have a certain access in the system (let's call the group "Verified")  and a form field ("User") that references this group so that submitters can only choose someone in that group. The issue is that the "Verified" group is now over 8000 people and it won't let me add any new people, but more people are getting access every day.  Our SP contacts say it is a Microsoft limitation.

If I were to create a second group ("Verified2"), is there a way to merge the 2 so that the "User" field will allow anyone in either of the 2 groups to be selected?  I'd rather not make that field open, as there would be no validation that the person entered in the field has the appropriate access.

Also, I have a query in Excel that pulls everyone in the "Verified" group. if I create a second group, can that query be updated to pull everyone in both groups, or would I need to create a second query?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does have a limit on the number of people in the group, which is 5000:
[image]

You can select different groups:
[image]

In addition, based on the large number of people in your group, I suggest you rebuild a query, which is also convenient for management.

Comment: I think OP wants to select users from multiple groups (selective) and not select multiple groups.

Comment: Correct Ganesh.  Like if Verified1 group was all verified users from A-L, and Verified2 group was all verified users from M-Z,   I want anyone from either group to be able to be entered into the "User" field so that all the verified users are able to be picked.